# Test effectiveness of CPU fan

Tags: cpu, fan, temperature

Is there a chance to see if my fan is working effectively?
I know, its a bit tricky to measure it. It is just that the CPU and RAM are not always working at the same level, which makes it difficult to see if my fan is adjusted in the case correctly. I am using a micro ATX and the fans might not be perfectly oriented in the case.

I can see fan speed and cpu temperature, but as I said cannot see if temperature decrease really comes from increased fan speed or if there are other effects (CPU going slower to prevent overheating)

[Screenshot with cpu speed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjKVz.png)

Comment: Checking whether fans are working correctly is easy. First make sure they are clean and undamaged. You're already able to measure the fan speed, so set the fan to 100% or run a stress test like prime95 and compare the measured speeds with the published specifications for the fan.  As far as how well you've designed your cooling in your case, that's not something you can directly measure, but you can make inferences from several other factors. If you have questions about placement of parts in your case, I suggest you research/ask in a forum or community for PC builders.

Comment: I am trying different positions of the fan now. 

I use [metrics2mqtt](https://github.com/jamiebegin/metrics2mqtt/blob/master/contrib/metrics2mqtt.ini) to monitor the cpu load and the software from the screenshot in the first post to monitor fan speed and temperature. I hope this way I get some better understanding of where the most suitable position is.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying different positions of the fan now. I use metrics2mqtt to monitor the cpu load and the software from the screenshot in the first post to monitor fan speed and temperature. I hope this way I get some better understanding of where the most suitable position is.